# Why would this command have exit code 1

Tags: java, unix

I am relatively new to UNIX and have a requirement to set the date/time on a server from a .jar file.

I have tried the following:

```
        java.lang.Runtime rt = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime();

        java.lang.Process p = rt.exec("sudo date --set=\"Tue Aug 11 10:10:20 BST 2015\"");
        p.waitFor();

        logger.warn("exit code:  " + p.exitValue());
```

The exit code is = 1, which apparently is a "general error". I have been able to run commands requiring sudo successfully in this way.

any thoughts?

Comment: sudo requires a password the first time you use it. maybe that's the problem. or the date format but I guess you have tested it in console first

Comment: @VeselinDavidov thank you for responding, I tried your suggestions but the result was the same - i.e. I entered a sudo command first so the password was active and triple checked the data format. any further ideas?

Comment: I still think it's the password. The problem is that JVM opens another console and the sudo you have typed doesn't count. Try "echo \"password\"|sudo date --set=\"Tue Aug 11 10:10:20 BST 2015\"" Where password is your password. This might not be the most secure way but should at least help you see the problem. Or you can read the output from the rt.exec

Comment: yeah you can read the output with inputstreamreader and print it as a normal string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Veselin may be interested also:

The problem was date is a shell command and i needed access to the shell - I have root access already the amended command is:

```
    java.lang.Process p = rt.exec(new String[] {"/bin/sh", "-c","sudo date --set=\"Tue Aug 11 10:10:20 BST 2015\""});
```

Hope this helps someone!